# Преобразование объекта bs4 в словарь

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, beautiful-soup

Производится парсинг данных с сайта:

```
r = requests.get('http://ip-api.com/') 
print(r)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

soup
```

Сам по себе soup имеет достаточно удобный вид, но непонятно как подтягивать данные из него, для последующего преобразования в pd.DataFrame:

```
{
  "country"     : "Russia",
  "countryCode" : "RU",
  "region"      : "MOW",
  "regionName"  : "Moscow",
  "city"        : "Moscow",
  "district"    : "",
  "zip"         : "125480",
  "lat"         : 55.7522,
  "lon"         : 37.6156,
  "timezone"    : "Europe/Moscow",
  "isp"         : "NCNET",
  "org"         : "",
  "as"          : "AS42610 PJSC Rostelecom",
  "mobile"      : false,
  "proxy"       : false,
  "query"       : "37.204.225.193"
}
```

Как из супа получить pd.DataFrame?

Comment: На правах оффтопа замечу, что на этом сайте вроде как лимит в 150 запросов в минуту. Я не знаю какая именно Вам нужна инфа из IP-адреса, но не проще ли использовать бесплатные базы geoip от maxmind? https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API может отдавать данные сразу в JSON, поэтому можно воспользоваться методом [`read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) и считать данные в DataFrame:

```
location_df = pd.read_json('http://ip-api.com/json', lines=True)
```

Для получения информации по нескольким адресам, у них есть [Batch API](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:batch):
Следуя примеру из документации, можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
ips = [
    {"query": "208.80.152.201", "fields": "city,country,countryCode,query", "lang": "ru"},
    {"query": "8.8.8.8"},
    {"query": "24.48.0.1"}
]

r = requests.post('http://ip-api.com/batch', json=ips)

locations_df = pd.read_json(r.content)
```

Comment: Хорошо, тогда следующий - этап - как в этом адресе прописать ip, если мне нужны данные с разных ip- адресов, иначе говоря, как заполнить таблицу теперь?

Comment: @StepanSokol У них еще batch API есть. Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Всопользуйтесь [pd.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
In [49]: url = 'https://ipinfo.io/AS42610'

In [50]: df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
           Netblock                                   Description  Num IPs
0    109.173.0.0/17                               PJSC Rostelecom    32768
1    178.140.0.0/16                               PJSC Rostelecom    65536
2    185.19.20.0/22                               PJSC Rostelecom     1024
3    188.255.0.0/17                               PJSC Rostelecom    32768
4     188.32.0.0/16                               PJSC Rostelecom    65536
5     37.110.0.0/17                     NCNET Broadband customers    32768
6   37.110.128.0/19                     NCNET Broadband customers     8192
7     37.204.0.0/16                               PJSC Rostelecom    65536
8     46.242.0.0/17                               PJSC Rostelecom    32768
9      5.228.0.0/16                               PJSC Rostelecom    65536
10   77.37.128.0/17                       NKS broadband customers    32768
11   84.253.64.0/18                               PJSC Rostelecom    16384
12   85.30.192.0/18                               PJSC Rostelecom    16384
13   87.240.40.0/21  Central Telegraph Public Joint-stock Company     2048
14   87.240.48.0/20  Central Telegraph Public Joint-stock Company     4096
15   90.154.64.0/18                               PJSC Rostelecom    16384
16   95.84.128.0/18                     NCNET Broadband customers    16384
17   95.84.192.0/18                               PJSC Rostelecom    16384
```

---

**UPDATE**: если пользоваться Batch API, как в ответе @Andrey, то можно задействовать [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
ips = [
    {"query": "208.80.152.201", "fields": "city,country,countryCode,query", "lang": "ru"},
    {"query": "8.8.8.8"},
    {"query": "24.48.0.1"}
]

r = requests.post('http://ip-api.com/batch', json=ips)
res = json_normalize(r.json(), errors='ignore')
```

результат:

```
In [65]: res
Out[65]:
                              as           city        country countryCode  ...  regionName   status             timezone    zip
0                            NaN  San Francisco            США          US  ...         NaN      NaN                  NaN    NaN
1             AS15169 Google LLC  Mountain View  United States          US  ...  California  success  America/Los_Angeles  94043
2  AS5769 Videotron Telecom Ltee         Québec         Canada          CA  ...      Quebec  success      America/Toronto    G1X

[3 rows x 14 columns]
```

одна строка в вертикальном виде:

```
In [66]: res.loc[2]
Out[66]:
as             AS5769 Videotron Telecom Ltee
city                                  Québec
country                               Canada
countryCode                               CA
isp                 Le Groupe Videotron Ltee
lat                                  46.7749
lon                                 -71.3344
org                           Videotron Ltee
query                              24.48.0.1
region                                    QC
regionName                            Quebec
status                               success
timezone                     America/Toronto
zip                                      G1X
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Мне надо подавать ip-адреса в парсер так, чтобы он мне возвращал данные по этим адресам

Comment: @StepanSokol, можете привести пример? Например парсим след. url, на выходе хоти получить вот такой DataFrame...?

Comment: Пример: Парсим http://ip-api.com/#37.204.225.194 (но как то так, чтобы был json как у комментатора выше) и получаем строку region, city, lat, lon, country zip и тд.

В дальнейшем ip после решетки будет меняться много раз и df должен дополняться постоянно новой информацией